# Send text and image through intent and set in the list (Recyclerview)

Tags: android-intent, android-recyclerview

With onActicityResult, I am able to set image in imageview from camera and gallery. I want to send image and text both to next activity which is having recycler view. 
Any suggestions would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do this @DEV

Comment: How? @Abhishekkumar

Comment: Please explain in brief? your requirement @DEV